# Delete sub object item on condition

Tags: javascript

I have this function to get a objects of lists.
Each entry in the lists object contains a object of that lists items.
One of those items is key called `not_visible`.
I want to delete that item entry from the lists object.
I have thought of doing it like bellow, but Im stuck as `value` is not accessible in the sub forEach.
I have included a snip of the lists object aswell.

Any guidance will be appreciated.

```
getListsObjectByNameItemVisibility: function() {
    var lists =  listsObjectByName(this);
    Object.entries(lists).forEach(
        ([key, value]) => {
            Object.entries(value['list_items']).forEach(
                ([subKey, subValue]) => {
                    if(subValue['not_visible'] === false){                              
                    }
                }
            );              
        }
    );
    return list;
},
```

[image]

Comment: Please post a [mcve] instead of pictures

Comment: Can you show your object

Comment: `delete subValue.not_visable` ?

Comment: @JonasW. if `not_visable` was true. then I want to delete `item 0` from the `list_items` object.

Comment: So you’re looking for [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)? (It should be used directly on the `value.list_items` *array* – no `Object.entries`.) Also, please make sure the correct spelling of “visible” is consistent across your question.

Comment: `delete value.list_items[subKey]` ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe theres a fancyer solution, but this is how i would do it, just search fr what to remove, and after it, removes (idk in Javascript but removing items inside a for loop on the same list usually goes bad)

```
itemsToRemove = []

lists.list_items.forEach(function(item, index) {
    if(!item.not_visible) {
        itemsToRemove.push(item);
    }
});

itemsToRemove.forEach(function(item, index) {
    const itemIndex = lists.list_items.indexOf(item);
    lists.list_items.splice(itemIndex, 1);
});
```

Comment: Oh btw, u could achieve this with filter with EASE

`lists.list_items = lists.list_items.filter(item => item.not_visible == true);`

forgot bout that lol

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution.
For each entry in the `lists` object,
if that item contains a sublist of items, loop backwards through each and check 
the visibility property.
If the property is true, remove from object.

and return object containing no hidden items.

```
getListsObjectByNameItemVisability: function() {
    var lists =  listsObjectByName(this);
    Object.entries(lists).forEach(
        ([key, value]) => {

            for( var i = value.list_items.length-1; i >= 0; i-- ) {
                if(value.list_items[i]['not_visible']){
                    delete value.list_items[i];
                }
            }

        }
    );
    return lists;
},
```